# Enviar email con archivo adjunto

Tags: java, email

Buen dia, intento enviar un correo electrónico con archivos adjuntos, pero el programa pero se genera un `NullPointerException`.
Este es el código para enviar el correo:

```
public static void enviarConGMail(String destinatario, String asunto, 
    String cuerpo, String remitente, String rutaImagen) {
    // Esto es lo que va delante de @gmail.com en tu cuenta de correo. Es el remitente también.
    //Para la dirección nomcuenta@gmail.com

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  //El servidor SMTP de Google
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", remitente);
    props.put("mail.smtp.clave", "xlnqopsuicgrdscc");    //La clave de la cuenta
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    //Usar autenticación mediante usuario y clave
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //Para conectar de manera segura al servidor SMTP
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //El puerto SMTP seguro de Google

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {

        //message.setText(cuerpo);
        BodyPart texto= new MimeBodyPart();
        texto.setText(cuerpo);
        BodyPart adjunto= new MimeBodyPart();
        adjunto.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(rutaImagen)));

        MimeMultipart m=new MimeMultipart();
        m.addBodyPart(texto);
        m.addBodyPart(adjunto);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(remitente));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(destinatario));   //Se podrían añadir varios de la misma manera
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        message.setContent(m);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", remitente, "xlnqopsuicgrdscc");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        transport.close();
    }
    catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();   //Si se produce un error
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te salta el NullPointerException? ¿Has mirado este hilo (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) sobre cómo tratar NullPointerExceptions?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)